# How can I create a shorcut of my snapshot of my virtual machine in VirtualBox with Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox

How can I create a shortcut of my snapshot of my virtual machine in VirtualBox with Ubuntu?

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: what do you mean by a "shortcut" of your snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the machine, choose a shortcut on the desktop - that puts it in your desktop folder, which you can then move wherever. It's a *.desktop file, so you can check its properties in order to copy the command if you want to use that to make a menu entry.

If what you want is a shortcut to a previous snapshot, but not the current state, without messing up the current state, you'll need to clone the machine (again from the right-click menu). Then restore the snapshot on the original, with the current state preserved in the clone.